# Laravel Queue not working when sending file

Tags: laravel, file, queue

I am using Laravel Queue to send files , but it seems that Laravel Queue is not working. In my PHP configuration file I have `memory_limit` set to 128 MB (and I don't want to change it). In the Laravel configuration file I have queue driver is sync (its not working when driver is database). But in the process I have got the following error:

> allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 31860068 bytes) PHP

Here is my logic.

```
    $storage = $this->configs[ 'storage' ];
    if( isset( $this->configs[ 'old_storage' ] ) ) {
        $old_storage = $this->configs[ 'old_storage' ];
    } else {
        throw new \Exception( 'Not found old storage' );
    }

    $files = $old_storage->files()->withTrashed()->get();

    try {
        if( $old_storage->testConnection()[ 'status' ] != 'true' ) {
            throw new \Exception( ufl( 'disk::disk.not_connection' ) . ' ' . $old_storage->name );
        }

        if( $storage->testConnection()[ 'status' ] != 'true' ) {
            throw new \Exception( ufl( 'disk::disk.not_connection' ) . ' ' . $storage->name );
        }

        foreach( $files as $file ) {
            try {
                //TODO Добавить логи в будущем (ошибка при копировании файла)
                $stream = $file->readStream();
                $file->setStorage( $storage->id );

                $file->storage()->getDriver()->putStream( $file->getRealDestination(), $stream );

                $file->putStream( $file->getRealDestination(), $stream );
            } catch( \Exception $e ) {
                $file->setStorage( $storage->id );
            }
            $file->save();
        }

        $old_storage->is_active = 0;
        $old_storage->status    = DiskStorage::STATUS_OK;
        $old_storage->save();
        $storage->is_active = 1;
        $storage->status    = DiskStorage::STATUS_OK;
        $storage->save();

    } catch( \Exception $e ) {
        //Откат
        foreach( $files as $file ) {
            $file->setStorage( $old_storage->id );
            $file->save();
        }

        $storage->status = DiskStorage::STATUS_OK;
        $storage->save();

        $old_storage->status = DiskStorage::STATUS_OK;
        $old_storage->save();

        throw new \Exception( $e->getMessage() );
    }
```

Comment: Try increasing memory limit in php.ini file

Comment: it is very bad suggestion, I want improve logic

Comment: Perhaps you need to close the resource streams. I haven't used Flysystem extensively, so it is just a guess

Comment: I dont want to leave my logic, I only want to improve it.